# Regex with multiline string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make regex for getting diff for each file from project path diff file. Here it is:

```
--- Training/main/1/a   (revision 18 06 2013 06:48)
+++ Training/main/1/a   (revision 18 06 2013 06:48)
@@ -1,1 +0,0 @@
-isdfsdfsdsadasdasd
\ No newline at end of file
--- Training/main/1/abc (revision After)
+++ Training/main/1/abc (revision After)
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+isdfsdfsdsadasdasd
\ No newline at end of file
--- Training/main/1/test.txt    (revision 18 06 2013 06:48)
+++ Training/main/1/test.txt    (revision After)
@@ -1,1 +1,3 @@
-sfaa
\ No newline at end of file
+sfaaasdasssssdsadasdas
+
+test with moving files on depot
\ No newline at end of file
```

How to create regex pattern to match each file's diff? For example to match:

Diff 1:

```
--- Training/main/1/a   (revision 18 06 2013 06:48)
+++ Training/main/1/a   (revision 18 06 2013 06:48)
@@ -1,1 +0,0 @@
-isdfsdfsdsadasdasd
\ No newline at end of file
```

Diff 2:

```
--- Training/main/1/abc (revision After)
+++ Training/main/1/abc (revision After)
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+isdfsdfsdsadasdasd
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: I've also tried this one:

`x = re.compile('(^---.+)---:', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`
But it also includes new line character at the end of matching string.

Comment: What about looking for string starting with:
`--- file_path revision
+++ file_path revision
@@ some_changes @@`

till the next occurency of this?

Answer (score 0):

If possible at all, can you generate the diffs separately? If you have access to the repository this should be the simplest solution.

Otherwise, you cannot do it via regex - any line can start with `---` or `+++`. The correct solution for splitting the changes is to actually parse the diff format and skip the indicated number of `+`, `-` lines and possible other indicators for each file chunk.

Comment: Not possible, I'm getting diff files from other system. Can't make it do diffs other way.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to do it by parsing the contents. If I remember correctly, the good enough way is for a chunk marked `@@ -x,y +z,u @@` you need to skip `max(y,u) + abs(y-u)`lines and you're at the next chunk (watch out for context lines and `\...` markers). It's an approximation, not a proper description though - check patch format for more info.